# : How can I change stripe test to live?

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, wallet, android-inapp-purchase

I created Stripe payment gateway with flutter it is working on test mode now,
I want to change to Live Mode ( I've updated the publishableKey and the secret ) in the StripeOptions() I must change **androidPayMode** and **merchantId** ?, if should change then  how it do? I can't find anything related to that.

```
static init() {
StripePayment.setOptions(StripeOptions(
    publishableKey:
        "my key",
    merchantId: "Test",
    androidPayMode: 'test'));
```

}

Answer (score 5):

you need to change from your test keys to live keys and set androidPayMode to production like this:

```
StripePayment.setOptions(StripeOptions(
    publishableKey:"public live key",
         merchantId: 'merchant.thegreatestmarkeplace', //merchantId
         androidPayMode: 'production'));
```

it's working for me on Android (live mode)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you also tell when we do the payment, where will that payment go, to which account? Because I haven't added any amount in Stripe.

Answer (score 2):

From Stripe's perspective, changing from your test keys to live keys is all that is needed.

I'm not familiar with the other options so you'll have to ask the maintainers of whatever library you're using or provide more detail about where/how these are used.